# Characterization of density through the interior

Tags: general-topology, difference-sets

I'm trying to prove an elemental exercise of general topology but I don't know how: Let $C = B \setminus A$, then $A$ is dense in $B$ if and only if $\operatorname{int}(C) = \varnothing$. Any hints or help are welcomed.

Comment: This follows from expanding all of the definitions.

Comment: Which definition of "dense" are you using? "Closure of $A$ equals $B$"?

Comment: @KentaS can you give me more details?

Comment: The "straight definition" you have written is not the definition of "A is dense in B."

Comment: That's why I coulnd't proved it, "A is dense in B if for every element $b \in B$ there exists $r>0$ such that $B(b,r) \cap A \neq \varnothing$", isn't it?

Comment: The definition of a topological space (see Wikipedia) is very broad and includes  spaces whose topologies cannot be described by metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following definition: "$A$ is dense in $B$ if $B = \text{closure}(A)$."

Suppose $\text{int}(C) \ne \varnothing$. Then there exists a point $x$ and an open ball $B(x, r)$ such that $x \in B(x, r) \subseteq C$. Consequently, $x$ cannot be a point in $\text{closure}(A)$ because any sequence of points that approaches $x$ would need to eventually belong to $B(x, r)$ which is outside $A$.

Suppose $\text{int}(C) = \varnothing$. Fix some point $x \in C$; it is not an interior poiont of $C$. For any fixed choice of $r_n > 0$, the ball $B(x, r_n)$ contains a point $x_n$ outside of $C$, i.e. $x_n \in A$. By doing this for $r_n = 1/n$, we obtain a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $A$ satisfying $|x_n - x| < 1/n$, so $x_n \to x$. This implies $x$ is a limit point of $A$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, all points of $C=B\setminus A$ are limit points of $A$, so $B$ is the closure of $A$.

---

Alternate definition of "$A$ is dense in $B$": for any element $b \in B$ and **any radius $r>0$** the intersectioon $B(b, r) \cap A$ is nonempty.

Comment: Okey, thanks for the answer. Anyway, let me know if the following reasoning is wrong: The assertion asked is equivalent to prove that $\operatorname{int}(C) \neq \varnothing$ if and only if $A$ is not dense in $B$. Let $b \in \operatorname{int}(C)\subseteq C$, then $b \notin A$. Thus, there doesn't exist $r>0$ such that $B(b,r) \cap A \neq \varnothing$, so the definition of density for $A$ doesn't hold. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is dense in $B$ then $\overline A\supseteq B$ so any nbhd of any $p\in B$ must intersect $A$ so any nbhd of any $p\in C$ must intersect $A$ so $no$ nbhd of any $p\in C$ can be a subset of $B$ \ $A =C$, that is, there are no non-empty nbhds that are subsets of $C$, that is, $int(C)=\emptyset$. Try this method for the reverse implication.

BTW it is standard usage that "$u$ intersects $v$" means $u\cap v\ne\emptyset.$And a nbhd of $p$ is a set $V$ such that there exists an open set $U$ with $p\in U\subseteq V$.